# Autofac: long-lived objects requiring short-lived objects during single method calls

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

I have a class `X` that I register in Autofac as single-instance because it's rather costly to create.

`X` has a method `DoSomething` that performs some action. However, to do its task in `DoSomething`, `X` needs additional dependencies. Typically, I'd inject them in the constructor, but in this case this gets difficult, because the dependency is bound to a narrower scope, e.g. instance-per-httprequest or instance-per-lifetime-scope. I can't use `Func<T>`, because this still resolves the objects in the lifetime in which the delegate is instantiated, so I don't gain anything.

The next option would have been to pass in the dependency as an argument to `DoSomething`, however the fact that there is a dependency is really just an implementation detail. In fact, I access X through an interface. I'd rather not cause a leaking abstraction by adding this parameter.

Resolving the dependency manually in the method (ie., service-locator style) isn't that great, either, of course. And even then I have the problem that I'm not sure how to access the proper `IComponentContext`. The class may be used in a web application or in a conventional application, or in a thread of a web application, but outside any request. How I do I determine the "current" lifetime scope?

So the basic problem is this:

```cs
class X : ISomething 
{
  public void DoSomething()
  {
    IDependency dependency = ?;
    dependency.UseMe();
    /* more stuff */
  }
}
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to inject something into the constructor that will later allow me to resolve the actual object inside the current lifetime scope, like so:

```cs
class X : ISomething 
{
  IResolveLater<IDependency> dependencyResolver;

  public X(IResolveLater<IDependency> dependencyResolver){
    this.dependencyResolver = dependencyResolver;
  }

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    IDependency dependency = dependency.Resolve();
    dependency.UseMe();
    /* more stuff */
  }
}
```

I'm certainly smelling design issues here, but I can't really put my finger on it. How can I solve this general problem: a long-lived object that requires locally-scoped, short-lived objects for single operations. I normally much prefer the different order: short-lived objects depending on long-lived objects.

I was also thinking about somehow moving the long-lived stuff out of X and create an additional, short-lived class `XHelper` that acts as some kind of "adapter":

```cs
class X 
{

  void DoSomething(IDependency dependency)
  {
    /* do something */
  }
}

class XHelper : ISomething
{
  X x;
  public XHelper(X x, IDependency dependency)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.dependency = dependency;
  }

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    x.DoSomething(dependency);
  }
}
```

Thus, when I need an ISomething, I'll resolve an XHelper (instead of an X) as needed which automatically gets the proper dependencies injected. It's a bit cumbersome that I need to introduce an additional type just for this.

How can I resolve this situation in the most elegant way?

Comment: My first thought on this was that when the lifetime discrepancy between the two objects is so big and at the same time the individual instance of `IDependency` is so influential and important, maybe there should be an abstraction that actually reflects that relationship. Other than that, where would the `IResolveLater` instance get the dependency instance from for an individual call to `DoSomething()`?

Comment: @GCATNM Would you care to elaborate on the "an abstraction that actually reflects that relationship" part? I think the `XHelper` class (ignore the naming) could be this abstraction. Re `IResolveLater`: it would somehow automagically resolve the instance from the "current" lifetime scope. Although I'm not sure how to define the semantics of "current". It could be, for example, the innermost (= mosted deeply nested) lifetime scope currently opened. But I'm not sure that this makes sense. At the moment, I think, the `XHelper` approach is the way to go.

Comment: The simplest way is to use a [`Func<Owned<IDependency>>`](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OwnedInstances)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your use case is actually a simple factory pattern in disguise.

Create a simple DependencyFactory that has a Create() method that returns instances of whatever concrete class you want that implements IDependency, then have your DependencyFactory implement an interface IDependencyFactory.

Register the IDependencyFactory with the container, and modify the constructor of Class X to take an IDependencyFactory.

Use the IDependencyFactory instance to resolve a concrete instance of IDependency in your method DoSomething() and call DoSomething() on it.